# Detect when a popup is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, onunload

I have a popup made with:

```
var popup = window.open(URL, ...) //content of popup is not in my control
```

I want to know when the popup is closed, and thought the below code could help me.

```
$(popup).unload()
```

However, Firefox initiates the unload event when the popup appears, not when it's closed!

Is there a reliable way to know when a popup is closed, by the opener?

I don't particularly like polling the popup asking every (say) 500ms if it's closed...

(I found this solution on [How to know when popup is closed in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846553/how-to-know-when-popup-is-closed-in-javascript))

Comment: this question has already been asked and answered.
try 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797560/set-a-callback-function-to-a-new-window-in-javascript

Comment: I don't kwow how is it related. Do you suggest to add a unload callback in the child window?

Comment: would you able to add a onbeforeunload call back in popup window ???

Answer (score 2):

If you can add a `onbeforeunload` `event` `handler` in popup then try something like this,

**parent:**

```
function parentCallback(){
  alert("popup is closed");
}

var popup = window.open(URL, ...);
```

**POPUP:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    window.opener.parentCallback();
    self.close();
};
```

else make use of `interval`, thats what i could suggest, something like

```
var pop_win = window.open(url,...);   
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
    if(pop_win.closed) {  
        clearInterval(timer);  
        alert('popup is closed');  
    }  
}, 1000);
```

Comment: OP states having no control of the content in the popup, though

Comment: what's the compatibility of the `onbeforeunload` callback? AFAIK it's a ie-nostrict-only thing...

Comment: http://pro-thoughts.blogspot.com/2006/03/onbeforeunload-event.html it is supported by almost all browser.

Comment: You're the only one who mentioned `windowRef.closed`, you get my vote. He didn't want to do polling, but unfortunately it seems impossible to do this correctly without doing so.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed

Answer (score 0):

It seems popup.location will return null if it's closed and an empty set if it's open.

```
popup.location // Open Window

=> Location 
      No Properties Defined

popup.location // Closed Window

=> null
```

Test with:

```
if (popup.location) {alert('hello')}
```

Comment: I guess that would require polling, though *sigh*

Comment: So are you suggesting to poll the popup object until it's location is null? Are there no alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is a bit old, but for others searching for the answer I think I have found a solution:

You might be able to do like this (it has worked for me anyway, also in FF):

**Parent:**

```
var popup = window.open("about:blank"); // Or whatever page you are loading
popup.onunload = function(){
    parent.location.reload();
        // or
    parent.alert("Popup closed!");
        // or any other handler in the parent window,
        // just remember to call it on the parent object.
};
```

Comment: Where you say `parent`, I'm pretty sure you meant `window`. `window` shouldn't change based on function context, only `this` does that as far as I'm aware.